# laravel запрос аналогичный SQL

Tags: php, sql, база-данных, laravel

Есть обычный SQL запрос:

```
$stmt=$connect->prepare("SELECT *  FROM DataBase WHERE Verification = 1 AND  Name LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%') LIMIT 10");
$stmt->bind_param("s",$search);
$stmt->execute();
$rows=$stmt->get_result();
 if($rows->num_rows>0){
   //...
 }
```

Как построить такой же на laravel?
Laravel-8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что-то типа

```sql
$users = DB::table('DataBase')
       ->where('Verification', '=', 1)
       ->whereRaw('Name LIKE CONCAT("%",?,"%")', [$search])
       ->get();
```

Comment: Благодарю, то что надо